# Approaching the Fourier transform of a damped cosine with a linear frequency chirp

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I want to take the Fourier transform of the following transient signal,
$$f(t) = e^{-t/\tau} \cos((\omega_0 + m t)t)$$, where $m$ is some gradient parameter in units of $\rm{Hz}/s$.
I thought this would be quite straight forward -- although most of my approaches have been made using Mathematica -- which struggles to provide anything useful.

I would have assumed the resultant function would have a Lorentzian-like peak profilein a similar way to if one takes the trivial Fourier transform of 
$$f(t) = e^{-t/\tau} \cos(\omega_0t)$$.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I can approach this, or, an alternative to Fourier transforming a damped sinusoidal with a linear (or even non linear) frequency, i.e. a chirp.

Comment: Hope this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248629/fourier-transform-of-cos-x2) is useful.

Comment: @the_candyman Very nice find. I'll let you know!

Comment: It appears you are dealing with a linear chirp signal. This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_spectrum#Linear_chirp) provides the Fourier transform for the "complex" and non-damped version, which appears quite complicated